# Posting Data from textBox in HTML to Restful Service using jQuery AJAX

Tags: html, wcf, jquery, wcf-rest

I am trying to post data from input values from textBoxes to restful service via jQuery and ajax. But im unable to do it.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
&nbsp;
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="LoginHtml.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="registration">
<h2>Login Account</h2>
<form id="registerUserForm">
<fieldset>
<p>
<input id="txtUserName" type="text" required="required" autofocus="true" placeholder="User Name"  />
</p>
<p> 
<input id="txtPassword"  type="password"  required="required" placeholder="Password" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" id="submitForm" autofocus="true" /><br>
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="Call()" ></input>
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
function Call() {

jQuery.support.cors = true;

var data = {};
data.uid = document.getElementById('txtUserName');
data.pwd = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
$.ajax({
 data: jQuery.toJSON(data),
 dataType: "json",
 url: "http://:xxxxxx:8080/Service1/Login",
 type: "GET",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 success: function (result) {alert("success");

    alert(result.d);}

error: function OnError(request, result, error) {


    alert(result);
}
});
```

Here is my code for service:

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   public UserProfile Login(string uid, string pwd)
    {
        UserProfile oUser = null;
        //UserDao userDao;

        using (UserProfileDataContext db = new UserProfileDataContext())
        {

            var u = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Username == uid && o.Password == pwd);

            if (u != null)
            {
                oUser = new UserProfile();
                oUser.Id = u.Id;
                oUser.Username = u.Username;
                oUser.Password = u.Password;
                oUser.Email = u.Email;

            }

        }

        return oUser;
    }
```

Tell me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think you make a mistakes in your code. your writing service is "post" and you call this using "GET". so please change this.

```
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try serializing your form:

```
 var data = $("#registerUserForm").serialize();
```

And change type to POST rather than GET

So ...

```
 $.ajax({
   data: data,
   url: "http://:xxxxxx:8080/Service1/Login",
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function (result) {
     alert("success");
     alert(result.d);
   }
   error: function OnError(request, result, error) {
     alert(result);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to return in Login method the following

```
 return Json(new { Id = oUser.Id, Username =  oUser.Username });
```

And then in Success function

```
 success: function (result) {
      alert("success");

      alert(result.Id);
}
```

And of course type must be POST in ajax call

Comment: the login method is working fine. i tried to call it from windows phone and it worked fine for me.